# Можно ли динамически создать типы из odata metadata чтобы динамически идентифицировать объекты json

Tags: c#, json, xml, metadata

Возможно ли создать такой сервис, и если возможно то как, который:
1. Получает описание контрактов (типов объектов) сервера  через $metadata (с этим проблем нет)
2. Динамически создает типы на основании metadata xml 
3. Запрашивает информацию с сервера и идентифицирует типы объектов на основании п2. 
(Проблема в том что сервер в одном ответе на запрос выдает объекты разных типов которые могут меняться)

Comment: `Проблема в том что сервер в одном ответе на запрос выдает объекты разных типов которые могут меняться` если в этом проблема, почему вы её не решаете, а вместо этого выдумаываете что то сложное с генерацией типов на лету?

Answer (score 0):

Можно собирать объекты через анонимные объекты, тип будет object. Придётся задействовать рефлексию, чтобы находить нужные поля (или огромный switch), а создать объект с нужным свойством и значением можно через IDictionary.

Пример Group By по одному полю:

```
var groupByTransformation = (GroupByTransformationNode)options.Apply?.ApplyClause?.Transformations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Kind == TransformationNodeKind.GroupBy);
if (groupByTransformation != null)
{
    var fields = groupByTransformation.GroupingProperties.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

    var groupedList = ((IQueryable<MyEntity>) query)
        .GroupBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(fields[0]).GetValue(x, null))
        .Select(x => new Dictionary<string, object> { { fields[0], x.Key } });      
}
```

На выходе получиться Json ничем не отличающийся от Json'а объекта